# Looking for a somewhat unanimous "web-related-definitions" resource

Tags: php, html, css, programming-languages

I am continually studying up on languages I have been using and learning, as well as always delving into new development concepts and languages. For books, I typically read O'Reilly, but online I'm not sure what my best bet is.

I know there are very accurate and very inaccurate sources out there and was wanting to know of a few good solid ones.

I've been using Wikipedia for reading up on JSON, AJAX and XML for example and can't help but wonder the reliability of the content.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wikipedia is usually fine. Do you have specific doubts about what a specific article or definition say? As it stands, this is a bit too broad I think.

Comment: If you don't trust a wikipedia article, start investigating the articles it cites.  As to a "single source of truth", you can read w3c specs and RFCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this site: http://martinfowler.com/intro.html
There a lot of definitions and useful documentations (especially about software [design](http://martinfowler.com/design.html)).
Hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: yes you did. Just picking you guy's brains for trusted resources